# Using Finger in Bash to display unique names

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a shell script that displays unique Names, user name and Date using finger command.

Right now when I enter finger, it displays..

```
Login     Name             Tty      Idle  Login Time   Office      
1xyz      xyz              pts/13         Dec  2 18:24 (76.126.34.32)
1xyz      xyz              pts/13         Dec  2 18:24 (76.126.34.32)
2xxxx     xxxx             pts/23      2  Dec  2 21:35 (108.252.136.12)
2zzzz     zzzz             pts/61     13  Dec  2 20:46 (24.4.205.223)
2yyyy     yyyy             pts/32     57  Dec  2 21:06 (205.154.255.145)
1zzz      zzz              pts/35     37  Dec  2 20:56 (71.198.36.189)
1zzz      zzz              pts/48     12  Dec  2 20:56 (71.198.36.189)
```

I would the script to eliminate the unique values of the username and display it like..

```
xyz        (1xyz)          Dec 2 18:24
xxxx       (2xxxx)         Dec 2 21:35
zzzz       (2zzzz)         Dec 2 20:46
yyyy       (2yyyy)         Dec 2 21:06
zzz        (1zzz)          Dec 2 20:56
```

the Name is in the first column and the user name is in () and Date is last column

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ugly but should work.

`finger | sed 's/\t/ /' | sed 's/pts\/[0-9]* *[0-9]*//' | awk '{print $2"\t("$1")\t"$3" "$4" "$5}' | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 0):

Unique names with `sort-u` is the easy part.
When you only want to parse the data in your example, you can try matching all strings in one command.

```
finger | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) *\([^ ]*\) *pts[^A-Z]*\([^(]*\).*/\2\t(\1)\t\3/'
```

However, this is hard work and waiting to fail. My `finger` returns

```
Login      Name                  Tty      Idle  Login Time   Where
notroot    notroot              *:0          -  Nov 26 15:30 console
notroot    notroot               pts/0      7d  Nov 26 15:30
notroot    notroot              *pts/1       -  Nov 26 15:30
```

You can try to improve the sed command, good luck with that!
I think the only way is looking at the columns: Read the finger output one line a time and slice each line with `${line:start:len}` into parts (and remove spaces afterwards). Have a nice count (and be aware for that_user_with_a_long_name).